# Facebook Open Graph aggregator sorting

Tags: facebook, sorting, facebook-opengraph, aggregation

I setup object, action, and aggregator.

1) For example, I posted 10 actions for the object with ID = 1. They show up in timeline.
2) Next I posted another 5 actions for the different object with ID = 2. They also show up in timeline.
3) Next I posted another 1 action for the third object with ID = 3. I see that in timeline aggregation only 9 counts for objectID 1.

**QUESTION**: Why the number decreased for the object with ID = 1? Why data are not properly summed.

Type of sort in this aggregation is "Favorite". Also I can't set "Custom" sort with "count" param - it is not saved.